# Listen to Keyboard and Mouse Chrome Hosted App

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am building a Chrome Hosted App, its some sort of time tracking software, which will monitor user activity, if he is working or not. The App is also supposed to listen to users keyboard strokes and mouse movements. I am not able to find any API in the documentation. Is it possible or not?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with [chrome.input.ime](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/input_ime) API.

> This allows your extension to handle keystrokes, set the composition, and manage the candidate window.

You can actually use, `onKeyEvent` for keyboard events or `onCandidateClicked` for mouse events as given examples. You may go through the documentation for more information.